# mounting NTFS bitlocker in linux

Tags: ntfs, disk-encryption, ntfs-3g

I use ntfs-3g from tuxera in RHEL/CentOS 7.9 to mount my windows 10 disk.  I have linux installed on a separate disk when I use linux.

```
mount -t ntfs-3g  /dev/sdb3  /mywin10
```

However I do this on another pc now that has Windows 10 with Bitlocker.
So the mount fails.

Is there, or will there ever be, a way in linux to mount an bitlocker encrypted ntfs partition?

Comment: Amazing what Google can do: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ntfs-3g+bitlocker+ntfs -> the 1st hit: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/04/how-to-mount-bitlocker-encrypted.html

Comment: thanks Richard.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is [Dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker) which I actually packaged some years ago for [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), thus you can use either `yum install dislocker` or `yum install fuse-dislocker`, depending on the actual way you would like to access it (source: https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker):

> Two binaries are of interest when wanting to decrypt a BitLocker encrypted partition:
>
> `dislocker-fuse`: binary using FUSE to dynamically decrypt the BitLocker-ed partition. You have to give it a mount point where, once keys are decrypted, a file named dislocker-file appears. This file is a virtual NTFS partition, so you can mount it as any NTFS partition and then read from or write to it. Note that writing to the NTFS virtual file will change the underlying BitLocker partition's content.
>
> `dislocker-file`: binary decrypting a BitLocker encrypted partition into a flat file. This file has to be given through command line and, once dislocker-file is finished, will be an NTFS partition. It won't have any link to the original BitLocker partition. Therefore, if you write to this file, the BitLocker volume won't change, only the NTFS file will. Note that this may take a long time to create that file, depending on the size of the encrypted partition. But afterward, once the partition is decrypted, the access to the NTFS partition will be faster. Another thing to think about is the size on your disk this binary needs: the same size as the volume you're trying to decrypt. Nevertheless, once the partition is decrypted, you can mount your file as any NTFS partition.